# Firebase ChildEventListener calls onChildChanged twice for one call to setValue

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I’m creating an Android app that is a SCUBA diving logbook. Upon updating an existing “dive log” to my Firebase database the onChildChanged event is called twice for only one call to setValue. From my logcat the first onChildChanged happens 0.034 seconds after the setValue call. The second onChildChanged happens 0.092 seconds after the first onChildChanged (0.126 seconds after the originating setValue call.)

Below is the relevant code and my data structure.
Any thoughts as to why I’m receiving two onChildChanged events for one call to setValue would be appreciated.

```
// save method in my DiveLog class
public static String save(@NonNull String userUid, @NonNull DiveLog diveLog) {
  if (diveLog.getDiveLogUid() == null
      || diveLog.getDiveLogUid().isEmpty()
      || diveLog.getDiveLogUid().equals(MySettings.NOT_AVAILABLE)) {
            String newDiveLogUid = nodeUserDiveLogs(userUid).push().getKey();
            diveLog.setDiveLogUid(newDiveLogUid);
            Timber.i("Created diveLog number %d.", diveLog.getDiveNumber());
            }

            nodeUserDiveLogs(userUid).child(diveLog.getDiveLogUid()).setValue(diveLog);
            Timber.i("Saved diveLog number %d.", diveLog.getDiveNumber());
            return diveLog.getDiveLogUid();
    }

// my DiveLogs DatabaseReference
public static DatabaseReference nodeUserDiveLogs(@NonNull String userUid) {
    return dbReference.child(NODE_DIVE_LOGS).child(userUid);
}

// my .addChildEventListener
private void addUserDiveLogsChildEventListener() {
    mUserDiveLogsChildEventListener = new UserDiveLogsChildEventListener();
    DiveLog.nodeUserDiveLogs(mUserUid)
        .addChildEventListener(mUserDiveLogsChildEventListener);
}        

// my onChildChanged event  
public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousDiveLogUid) {
    // TODO: Figure out why onChildChanged is called twice for each DiveLog.save().
    if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
        DiveLog changedDiveLog = dataSnapshot.getValue(DiveLog.class);
        Timber.i("DiveLog: onChildChanged(). Dive Log Number: %d", changedDiveLog.getDiveNumber());
    }
}

// My database structure:
//  diveLogs
//      ---> UserUid <<< ChildEventListener Node
//          ---> diveLogUid
//              ---> diveLogField
//              ---> diveLogField
//              ---> diveLogField
//                  .   
//                  .
//                  .
//          ---> diveLogUid
//              ---> diveLogField
//              ---> diveLogField
//              ---> diveLogField
//                  .   
//                  .
//                  .
```

UPDATE: 11/28/2016
For anyone that might be interested, here’s an update on this issue.

I’ve been in contact with firebase support and they have confirmed that this issue is a bug. [FYI, my experience with firebase support has been good. They have been responsive in looking into this issue.]

On 11/21/2016 firebase support told me:

Although the cause has been found, our engineers are still looking for a suitable solution. I have followed up and will update you on the progress.

In the meantime, you can try to manually check for dive log equality to avoid the duplicate change event. You'll have to implement the equals() and hashCode() on Divelog. I used the IDE to generate it. There is also an option to use EqualsBuilder for deep equality.

Though, this workaround will not let you avoid the first change event for the same float values. Perhaps, you can retrieve the exact dive log from your 'dive log list' on the client and then compare rather than using a 'temp' dive log to solve that.

```
private DiveLog temp = null;

@Override
public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousDiveLogUid) {

    DiveLog changedDiveLog = dataSnapshot.getValue(DiveLog.class);
    Timber.i("DiveLog: RAW onChildChanged(). Dive Log Number: %d",
changedDiveLog.getDiveNumber());

if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
    if(temp != null &&
            //check if the same dive log
            temp.getDiveLogUid().equals(changedDiveLog.getDiveLogUid()) &&
            //compare
            temp.equals(changedDiveLog)){
        //skip change event
        return;
    }
    temp = changedDiveLog;
    Timber.i("DiveLog: onChildChanged(). Dive Log Number: %d", changedDiveLog.getDiveNumber());
    //do stuff
}
}
```

And on 11/22/2016 firebase support followed up with this suggestion:
A workaround suggested by our engineers is to make sure to use longs if you're writing a whole number. E.g.:

```
if (Math.floor(x) == x) {
   ref.set((long)x);
}
```

Note that this assumes that your values will be between LONG_MIN and LONG_MAX. Else, you may need some additional logic so you don't convert larger numbers to a long.

As you are using this inside a class, for now, you can perform the update on a direct reference of that field and remove that field from the class (a lot of work).

Sorry, but this is definitely a bug in the SDK and the solution is not entirely straightforward, so we could not share any definite dates when the fix will be released as of the moment.

Last below is simplified code that reproduces the issue:

```
package divelog.divelog;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        final DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("divelog");

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Changing", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
                //No issue with decimals
                //Foo foo = new Foo(0.1f);

                //Problem with saving floats that don't have decimals
                Foo foo = new Foo(1f);
                ref.child("child1").setValue(foo);
            }
        });

        ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Log.i("TEST", "changed: " + dataSnapshot.getValue());
                Log.i("TEST", "changed: " + ((Map)dataSnapshot.getValue()).get("val").getClass());
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        Foo foo = new Foo(1f);
        ref.child("child1").setValue(foo);
    }

}


package divelog.divelog;

public class Foo {
    private float val;

    public Foo(float val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    public Foo() {
    }

    public float getVal() {
        return val;
    }

    public void setVal(float val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Foo{" +
                "val=" + val +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: There are multiple reasons this could happen. The most likely one is that the write operation violations the security rules and thus gets rejected on the server. Could that be happening here? It will be easier to say more if you give some more details on the actual two change events that you see. What data is in them?

Comment: Thanks for you quick response. I’m able to read and write my DiveLog class to the Firebase database so I don’t think there a rule problem. The rule associated with my DiveLog class is as follows:

    "diveLogs": {
 "$uid":{
 ".read": "auth.uid == $uid",
 ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
        }
    },

Comment: The Datasnapshots between the first and second are different slightly. All of the field values are identical except for those that are a Double. The first Datasnapshot the Double values have a number after a decimal point, while the second Datasnapshot has no decimal point. (eg: airUsed=2500.0, waterTemperature=77.0 VS airUsed=2500, waterTemperature=77)

Comment: When i export the data to a JSON file it looks like:

Comment: "diveLogs" : {
    "SGUtgr6kE4WHpkKTuHzpVVcYXuF2" : {
      "-KR-v7i61ovLJVebmEPa" : {
        "accumulatedBottomTimeToDate" : 0,
        "airTemperature" : 70,
        "airUsed" : 0,